# Sequelize bulk create that doesn't fail if one row fails

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Is it possible to create a bulk create that will not fail if any of the rows fail and returns all the rows which failed to insert into the database.
ex: I am inserting 1000 users into database, 10 of them fail, can I get details of those 10 failed ones along with the reason for failure
I am using mariadb.

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5794) i think you need to have a .catch block taht handles errors. it's different than an .error block. There's an example of that at the bottom of [this](https://medium.com/@hz.bird55/using-sequelize-bulkcreate-method-with-mysql-database-1ebd1bae2109)  page

Comment: What do you mean failed to insert? sequelize model validation didn't pass or violate constraints?

Comment: @slideshowp2 if the model validation fails